# identifying key columns/features used by decision tree regression

Tags: r, machine-learning, azure-machine-learning-service

In Azure ML, I have a predictive regression model using boosted decision tree regression and it is reasonably accurate.

The input dataset has over 450 columns and the model has done a good job of predicting against test data sets, without over-fitting.

To report on the result i need to know what features/columns the model mainly used to make predictions but i cant find this information easily when looking at the trained model data.

How do i identify this information? Im happy to import the result dataset into R  to help find this but I just need pointers on what direction to start working in.

Comment: You would need the model object in R, not just the resulting data frame. Am I understanding correctly that you are using some kind of azure-ml library for your model, not an R package?

Comment: im doing all processing in Azure ML Studio online toolset.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly, in using Microsoft Azure Machine Learning, when looking at the features that is mainly used to make predictions, it is found on the **output of the Train Model** module.

But on using Decision Trees as your algorithm, the output of your Train Model module would be the constructed '**trees**' of the algorithm, and it looks like this:

[image]

To know the features that made impact on predictions while using Decision Trees algorithms, you can use the **Permutation Feature Importance** module. Look at the sample experiment below:

[image]

The parameters of Permutation Feature Importance are **Random Seed** and **Metric for Measuring Performance** *(in this case, Regression - Coefficient of Determination)*

The **left input** of **Permutation Feature Importance** is **your trained model**, and the **right input** is **your test data**.

The output of Permutation Feature Importance looks like this:

[image]

You can add **Execute R Script to extract the Features and Scores** from Permutation Feature Importance module.